# How to detect addition of new serial port?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, serial-port, delphi-xe2

To communicate with micro controllers I use the serial port. I use TCommPortDriver 2.1 which works fine. However, it lacks the ability to detect the addition or removal of new comports. This happens regularly during a session.

Is there an event that tells when a comport has been added or removed?

**Update 1**

I tried the first suggestion of RRUZ and turned it into a standalone program. It reacts on a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` when the cable is plugged in or out, but `WParam` does not show arrival or removal of the device. Results are:

```
msg = 537, wparam = 7, lparam = 0
msg = 537, wparam = 7, lparam = 0
msg = 537, wparam = 7, lparam = 0
```

The first message is sent when the USB cable is plugged out and the next two when it is plugged in.
The message part shows the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message (537) but `WParam` is 7, which is not `WM_DEVICECHANGE` or `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`. I modified the code somewhat in order the message to be processed but as `LParam` is zero this is no use. Results are identical to VCL and FMX. As a check see code below.

**Update 2**

I now got the WMI code running. It only fires when a COM port is added, no reaction when one is removed. Results:

```
TargetInstance.ClassGuid      : {4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} 
TargetInstance.Description    : Arduino Mega ADK R3 
TargetInstance.Name           : Arduino Mega ADK R3 (COM4) 
TargetInstance.PNPDeviceID    : USB\VID_2341&PID_0044\64935343733351E0E1D1 
TargetInstance.Status         : OK
```

Might this explain the fact that in the other code this is not seen as the addition of a COM port? It appears to see the new connection as a USB port (what it actually is). The Arduino driver translates this into a COM port but that is not recognized by WMI. Windows messaging 'sees' a COM port change but cannot detect whether it is added or removed.

Anyhow: the device change works. I only need to enumerate the COM ports to see which one are actually present and that was something I already did manually. Now I can do that automatically with `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. I just add an event to the CPDrv component.

Thanks RRUZ for your code and help!

```
  unit dev_change;

  interface

  uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

  type
    TProc = procedure (text: string) of object;

    BroadcastHdr  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
    DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = packed record
      dbch_size: DWORD;
      dbch_devicetype: DWORD;
      dbch_reserved: DWORD;
    end;
    TDevBroadcastHdr = DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;

  type
    PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;
    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE = record
      dbcc_size: DWORD;
      dbcc_devicetype: DWORD;
      dbcc_reserved: DWORD;
      dbcc_classguid: TGUID;
      dbcc_name: Char;
    end;
    TDevBroadcastDeviceInterface = DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;

  const
    DBT_DEVICESOMETHING        = $0007;
    DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL          = $8000;
    DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE   = $8004;
    DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = $00000005;

  type
    TDeviceNotifyProc = procedure(Sender: TObject; const DeviceName: String) of Object;
    TDeviceNotifier = class
    private
      hRecipient: HWND;
      FNotificationHandle: Pointer;
      FDeviceArrival: TDeviceNotifyProc;
      FDeviceRemoval: TDeviceNotifyProc;
      FOnWin: TProc;

      procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);

    public
      constructor Create(GUID_DEVINTERFACE : TGUID);
      property OnDeviceArrival: TDeviceNotifyProc read FDeviceArrival write FDeviceArrival;
      property OnDeviceRemoval: TDeviceNotifyProc read FDeviceRemoval write FDeviceRemoval;
      destructor Destroy; override;

      property OnWin: TProc read FOnWin write FOnWin;
    end;

    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Memo: TMemo;
      procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    private
      { Private declarations }
      DeviceNotifier : TDeviceNotifier;
    public
      { Public declarations }
      procedure arrival(Sender: TObject; const DeviceName: String);
      procedure report (text: string);
    end;

  var
    Form1: TForm1;

  implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

  constructor TDeviceNotifier.Create(GUID_DEVINTERFACE : TGUID);
  var
    NotificationFilter: TDevBroadcastDeviceInterface;
  begin
    inherited Create;
    hRecipient := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
    ZeroMemory (@NotificationFilter, SizeOf(NotificationFilter));
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_size := SizeOf(NotificationFilter);
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid  := GUID_DEVINTERFACE;
    //register the device class to monitor
    FNotificationHandle := RegisterDeviceNotification(hRecipient, @NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
  end;

  procedure TDeviceNotifier.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  var
    Dbi: PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface;
  begin
    OnWin (Format ('msg = %d, wparam = %d, lparam = %d', [msg.Msg, msg.WParam, msg.LParam]));
    with Msg do
    if (Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE) and ((WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL) or (WParam = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE) or
                                    (WParam = DBT_DEVICESOMETHING)) then
    try
      Dbi := PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface (LParam);
      if Dbi.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE then
      begin
        if WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL then
        begin
          if Assigned(FDeviceArrival) then
            FDeviceArrival(Self, PChar(@Dbi.dbcc_name));
        end
        else
        if WParam = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE then
        begin
          if Assigned(FDeviceRemoval) then
            FDeviceRemoval(Self, PChar(@Dbi.dbcc_name));
        end;
      end;
    except
      Result := DefWindowProc(hRecipient, Msg, WParam, LParam);
    end
    else
      Result := DefWindowProc(hRecipient, Msg, WParam, LParam);
  end;

  destructor TDeviceNotifier.Destroy;
  begin
    UnregisterDeviceNotification(FNotificationHandle);
    DeallocateHWnd(hRecipient);
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.arrival(Sender: TObject; const DeviceName: String);
  begin
     report (DeviceName);

     ShowMessage(DeviceName);
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  const
    GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT  : TGUID = '{86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73}';
  begin
    DeviceNotifier:=TDeviceNotifier.Create(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT);
    DeviceNotifier.FDeviceArrival:=arrival;
    DeviceNotifier.OnWin := report;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    DeviceNotifier.Free;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.report (text: string);
  begin
     Memo.Lines.Add (text);
  end;

  end.
```

Comment: You might have some luck using WMI events, just use DEVICE_CHANGE event and look for newly added serial ports

Comment: The posted WMI code does not include the removal device detection, for that you must change the WQL sentence to `Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA "Win32_PnPEntity" AND TargetInstance.ClassGuid="{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"`

Comment: or for detect the arrival or remove of the device using a single WQL sentence you can use the `__InstanceOperationEvent` WMI event.

Comment: +1 for your thorough explanations. I tested __InstanceOperationEvent which works, but one needs some postprocessing as it is not possible to distinguish between deletion and addition from the reponse. I got my component ready and it really is a pleasure to see it reacting on removals and additions. Thanks for your code and help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function passing the [`DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure with the [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) device interface class.

Try this sample.

```
type
  PDevBroadcastHdr  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
  DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = packed record
    dbch_size: DWORD;
    dbch_devicetype: DWORD;
    dbch_reserved: DWORD;
  end;
  TDevBroadcastHdr = DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;

type
  PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface  = ^DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;
  DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE = record
    dbcc_size: DWORD;
    dbcc_devicetype: DWORD;
    dbcc_reserved: DWORD;
    dbcc_classguid: TGUID;
    dbcc_name: Char;
  end;
  TDevBroadcastDeviceInterface = DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE;

const
  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL          = $8000;
  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE   = $8004;
  DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = $00000005;

type
  TDeviceNotifyProc = procedure(Sender: TObject; const DeviceName: String) of Object;
  TDeviceNotifier = class
  private
    hRecipient: HWND;
    FNotificationHandle: Pointer;
    FDeviceArrival: TDeviceNotifyProc;
    FDeviceRemoval: TDeviceNotifyProc;
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create(GUID_DEVINTERFACE : TGUID);
    property OnDeviceArrival: TDeviceNotifyProc read FDeviceArrival write FDeviceArrival;
    property OnDeviceRemoval: TDeviceNotifyProc read FDeviceRemoval write FDeviceRemoval;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

type
  TForm17 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    DeviceNotifier : TDeviceNotifier;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure arrival(Sender: TObject; const DeviceName: String);
  end;

var
  Form17: TForm17;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TDeviceNotifier.Create(GUID_DEVINTERFACE : TGUID);
var
  NotificationFilter: TDevBroadcastDeviceInterface;
begin
  inherited Create;
  hRecipient := AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
  ZeroMemory(@NotificationFilter, SizeOf(NotificationFilter));
  NotificationFilter.dbcc_size := SizeOf(NotificationFilter);
  NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype := DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
  NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid  := GUID_DEVINTERFACE;
  //register the device class to monitor
  FNotificationHandle := RegisterDeviceNotification(hRecipient, @NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
end;

procedure TDeviceNotifier.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  Dbi: PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface;
begin
  with Msg do
  if (Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE) and ((WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL) or (WParam = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE)) then
  try
    Dbi := PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface(LParam);
    if Dbi.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE then
    begin
      if WParam = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL then
      begin
        if Assigned(FDeviceArrival) then
          FDeviceArrival(Self, PChar(@Dbi.dbcc_name));
      end
      else
      if WParam = DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE then
      begin
        if Assigned(FDeviceRemoval) then
          FDeviceRemoval(Self, PChar(@Dbi.dbcc_name));
      end;
    end;
  except
    Result := DefWindowProc(hRecipient, Msg, WParam, LParam);
  end
  else
    Result := DefWindowProc(hRecipient, Msg, WParam, LParam);
end;

destructor TDeviceNotifier.Destroy;
begin
  UnregisterDeviceNotification(FNotificationHandle);
  DeallocateHWnd(hRecipient);
  inherited;
end;



procedure TForm17.arrival(Sender: TObject; const DeviceName: String);
begin
  ShowMessage(DeviceName);
end;

procedure TForm17.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT  : TGUID = '{86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73}';
begin      
  DeviceNotifier:=TDeviceNotifier.Create(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT);
  DeviceNotifier.FDeviceArrival:=arrival;
end;

procedure TForm17.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeviceNotifier.Free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Wew, thanks a lot! I added a form to my current application with the code you provided. When changing the com port WndProc is called but not arrival. A close inspection of `Msg` shows that its `Msg` is indeed `WM_DEVICECHANGE. WParam` is 7, not `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` (all other are 0). Changing the condition such that it is executed when `WParam` is 7, `Dbi := PDevBroadcastDeviceInterface (LParam);` returns `nil`, I should have know because `LParam` = 0. `WndProc` is only called once when changing the com port. Any ideas?

Comment: @Arnold, what kind of serial port are you adding? because I tried using a [USB serial port adapter](http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-SERIAL-PORT-ADAPTER-F5U409-CU/dp/B00009L7MI) and adding [virtual serial ports](http://www.mks.zp.ua/products/vspdxp/) and in both cases the code works fine (Windows 7 x64).

Comment: I add a USB cable which is (also) seen as a serial port by the ComPortDriver.

Comment: Maybe something in your app is interfering with the device notifications, can you try the code in a plain vanilla vcl form app?

Comment: This does not change the results. See my report in the update of the question.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is use the WMI Events, on this case using the `__InstanceCreationEvent` Event and the [`Win32_PnPEntity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class you can filter the serial ports added using the [`{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class GUID, writting a WQL sentence like so

```
Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA "Win32_PnPEntity" AND TargetInstance.ClassGuid="{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"
```

Try this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  {$IF CompilerVersion > 18.5}
  Forms,
  {$IFEND}
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  WbemScripting_TLB;

type
  TWmiAsyncEvent = class
  private
    FWQL      : string;
    FSink     : TSWbemSink;
    FLocator  : ISWbemLocator;
    FServices : ISWbemServices;
    procedure EventReceived(ASender: TObject; const objWbemObject: ISWbemObject; const objWbemAsyncContext: ISWbemNamedValueSet);
  public
    procedure  Start;
    constructor Create;
    Destructor Destroy;override;
  end;

//Detect when a key was pressed in the console window
function KeyPressed:Boolean;
var
  lpNumberOfEvents     : DWORD;
  lpBuffer             : TInputRecord;
  lpNumberOfEventsRead : DWORD;
  nStdHandle           : THandle;
begin
  Result:=false;
  nStdHandle := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  lpNumberOfEvents:=0;
  GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(nStdHandle,lpNumberOfEvents);
  if lpNumberOfEvents<> 0 then
  begin
    PeekConsoleInput(nStdHandle,lpBuffer,1,lpNumberOfEventsRead);
    if lpNumberOfEventsRead <> 0 then
    begin
      if lpBuffer.EventType = KEY_EVENT then
      begin
        if lpBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown then
          Result:=true
        else
          FlushConsoleInputBuffer(nStdHandle);
      end
      else
      FlushConsoleInputBuffer(nStdHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;

{ TWmiAsyncEvent }

constructor TWmiAsyncEvent.Create;
const
  strServer    ='.';
  strNamespace ='root\CIMV2';
  strUser      ='';
  strPassword  ='';
begin
  inherited Create;
  CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
  FLocator  := CoSWbemLocator.Create;
  FServices := FLocator.ConnectServer(strServer, strNamespace, strUser, strPassword, '', '', wbemConnectFlagUseMaxWait, nil);
  FSink     := TSWbemSink.Create(nil);
  FSink.OnObjectReady := EventReceived;
  FWQL:='Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 '+
        'Where TargetInstance ISA "Win32_PnPEntity" AND TargetInstance.ClassGuid="{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}" ';

end;

destructor TWmiAsyncEvent.Destroy;
begin
  if FSink<>nil then
    FSink.Cancel;
  FLocator  :=nil;
  FServices :=nil;
  FSink     :=nil;
  CoUninitialize;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWmiAsyncEvent.EventReceived(ASender: TObject;
  const objWbemObject: ISWbemObject;
  const objWbemAsyncContext: ISWbemNamedValueSet);
var
  PropVal: OLEVariant;
begin
  PropVal := objWbemObject;
  Writeln(Format('TargetInstance.ClassGuid      : %s ',[String(PropVal.TargetInstance.ClassGuid)]));
  Writeln(Format('TargetInstance.Description    : %s ',[String(PropVal.TargetInstance.Description)]));
  Writeln(Format('TargetInstance.Name           : %s ',[String(PropVal.TargetInstance.Name)]));
  Writeln(Format('TargetInstance.PNPDeviceID    : %s ',[String(PropVal.TargetInstance.PNPDeviceID)]));
  Writeln(Format('TargetInstance.Status         : %s ',[String(PropVal.TargetInstance.Status)]));
end;

procedure TWmiAsyncEvent.Start;
begin
  Writeln('Listening events...Press Any key to exit');
  FServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(FSink.DefaultInterface,FWQL,'WQL', 0, nil, nil);
end;

var
   AsyncEvent : TWmiAsyncEvent;
begin
 try
    AsyncEvent:=TWmiAsyncEvent.Create;
    try
      AsyncEvent.Start;
      //The next loop is only necessary in this sample console sample app
      //In VCL forms Apps you don't need use a loop
      while not KeyPressed do
      begin
          {$IF CompilerVersion > 18.5}
          Sleep(100);
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          {$IFEND}
      end;
    finally
      AsyncEvent.Free;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
end.
```

Comment: I love the way you play with WMI, RRUZ! +1